# floodfill algorithm - leaving out the edge

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

so far i have implemented a floodfill algorithm. I wanted to tweak it, so that it would leave out the edge. To demonstrate this i uploaded an image:

[image]

Image 1 is the image that i want to modify. Image 3 is what my algorithm is supposed to do. **Image 2 is my current result.**

So in this case the targetColor is white and the replacementColor is green;

Here is pseudocode of what i have done so far.

```cpp
doFloodFill(x,y,targetColor,replacementcolor) {

    if (x and y not in bounds of image) {
       return
    }

    if (color(x,y) IS NOT targetColor) {
       return
    }

    if (color(x+1, y) IS NOT targetColorOfFloodFill AND color(x+1, y) IS NOT replacementColor OR
        color(x-1, y) IS NOT targetColorOfFloodFill AND color(x-1, y) IS NOT replacementColor OR
        color(x, y+1) IS NOT targetColorOfFloodFill AND color(x, y+1) IS NOT replacementColor OR
        color(y, y-1) IS NOT targetColorOfFloodFill AND color(x, y-1) IS NOT replacementColor) {
        return;
    }

    image.setColor(x, y, replacementColor)

    doFloodFill(x+3,y,targetcolor,replacementcolor)
    doFloodFill(x-3,y,targetcolor,replacementcolor)
    doFloodFill(x,y+3,targetcolor,replacementcolor)
    doFloodFill(x,y-3,targetcolor,replacementcolor)
}
```

This tweak is implemented into my floodfill. Leaving it out results in a working floodFill algorithm without any problems. The actual question would be: how can i differentiate an edge pixel from a pixel with different color within the area?

P.S: **we can assume that x, y are starting from within the area**

Comment: What is `color(x+1)`? Do you maybe intend to write `color(x+1,y)`?

Comment: yes thats what that means, im gonna edit that

Comment: You’re going to get best replies if you post actual, working and complete code. Pseudocode and code fragments are hard to work with. See [mre].

Comment: You said image 2 is the desired result and image 3 is the actual result. Do you perhaps mean it the other way around? Not saying that's the case, but it seems like it might make more sense that way (although I could just be misinterpreting). Also, as noted above, a self-contained example would help. (You could perhaps print the output to a console to minimize dependencies.)

Comment: Yes, im sorry, you are right. 2 is the desired result. I now have added my floodfill method, this should be alot more insightful.

Comment: One possible solution might be to flood-fill the area outside the area of interest (the exterior black area in your example). Whenever the flood fill is stopped (e.g. by a white pixel), flag the pixel that stopped the flood fill as an edge pixel. Then flood fill the interior and stop whenever a pixel flagged as an edge pixel is reached. Perhaps someone else will offer a better approach, but that's the first thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go as well for the floodfill complement.

Still, an other idea:

- Floodfill like usual
- Keep track of one pixel of the border: e.g pixel at the utmost top
- Then follow the border like a mouse looking for escape and make it white again.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

const M = `
00000000000000000000
00000110011111110000
00001111111110000000
00011111111111100000
00111111111101110010
01111111101111110010
01111111111111110110
01111111111111111110
01111111111111111100
01111111111111111100
01111111111111111100
01111111111111111000
00111111111111111000
00111111111111110000
00011111111111100000
00000000000000000000
`.trim().split('\n').map(x=>x.trim().split('').map(x=>parseInt(x)))

const mat = ({ x, y }, v) => {
  if (v) {
    M[y][x] = v
  }
  return M[y][x]
}
const left = ({x,y}) => ({ x: y, y: -x })
const right = ({x,y}) => ({ x: -y, y: x })
const back = ({x, y}) => ({ x: -x, y: -y})
const front = (pos, { x, y }) => ({ x: pos.x + x, y: pos.y + y })
const splinter = { 
  pos: {
    x: 5, 
    y: 1
  },
  orig: {
    x: 5,
    y: 1
  },
  dir: { x: 1, y: 0 },
  atStart() {
    return this.pos.x === this.orig.x && this.pos.y === this.orig.y
  },
  move () {
    if (this.atStart() && mat(this.pos) === 2) { return false }
    // wall on left
    if (mat(front(this.pos, left(this.dir))) === 0) {
      // wall on front
      if (mat(front(this.pos, this.dir)) === 0) {
        // wall on right
        if (mat(front(this.pos, right(this.dir))) === 0) {
          this.dir = back(this.dir)
        } else {
          this.dir = right(this.dir)
        }
      }
      this.poop()
    } else {
      this.dir = left(this.dir)
    }
    this.moveForward()
    return true
  },
  moveForward () {
    this.pos.x += this.dir.x
    this.pos.y += this.dir.y
  },
  poop () {
    mat({ x: this.pos.x, y: this.pos.y }, 2)
  },
  sprite () {
    if (this.atStart()) { return 'X' }
    if (this.dir.x === -1 && this.dir.y === 0) { return '←' }
    if (this.dir.x === 1 && this.dir.y === 0) { return '→'}
    if (this.dir.x === 0 && this.dir.y === 1) { return '↓' }
    if (this.dir.x === 0 && this.dir.y === -1) { return '↑' }
  }
}

function redraw () {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  const dw = canvas.width / M[0].length
  const dh = canvas.height / M.length
  const fill = ({ x, y }, color) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = color
    ctx.fillRect(x * dw, y * dh, dw, dh)
  }
  const colors = {
    1: 'green',
    0: 'black',
    2: 'white'
  }
  M.forEach((row, i) => {
    row.forEach((el, j) => {
      fill({ x: j, y: i }, colors[el])
    })
  })
  const char = splinter.sprite()
  ctx.strokeText(char, (splinter.pos.x + 0.1) * dw, (splinter.pos.y + 0.8) * dh)
}
redraw()
document.querySelector('button').onclick = _ => {
  splinter.move(); redraw()
}
document.querySelector('button.allmoves').onclick = _ => {
  while(splinter.move()){}
  redraw()
}
```

```css
canvas{background:#eeeeee;}
```

```html
<canvas width="160" height="160"></canvas>
<button>move, rat</button>
<button class="allmoves">move for your life, rat</button>
```

Comment: Good idea. There is a small gap in step two. How would you get a single pixel on the outer border to start with?

Comment: @Trilarion when floodfilling (in op: ```image.setColor(x,y)```), we just have to keep the utmost top: ```topPixel = topPixel.x < x? topPixel: {x, y}```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i also finally implemented. Thank you so much

Comment: glad to be of help! I'd advise you to consider using the approach proposed by Tilarion though, my reason is that there are already existing floodfill algorithms so you don't have to implement any (and eventually there are existing low level implems which (even though complement has more pixels to consider) make it faster anyway!). As a side note, maybe an erosion of 1pixel could do it (have not tested it though)

Comment: There is a problem. the mouse seems to get stuck when it comes to passages that have a width of 1px, do you know a fix for it?

Comment: If you look at my answer, which is a scenario that the mouse should be able to solve,  as you can see it doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

First flood fill the black outer area in image 1 for example by starting with the pixel in the upper left corner of the image. Either use a color you haven't used yet (purple for example) or construct a mask during the filing.

Then fill the white area green in the central object like you did but without any tweaks of the algorithm. Just ordinary flood filling.

Finally, go through all the pixels in the second fill and turn those that border the first fill white again.

You have achieved your goal. If you did not use masks, make sure to fill the area resulting from the first fill black again.

No tweaking of the flood fill algorithm was needed.

Comment: scg had the same or a very similar idea earlier and posted it as comment below the question. I hadn't read it before posting this answer but the credits should of course go to him too.