# Algorithm to fill out a monochrome area - ideas?

Tags: image, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm which pretty much does the same as flood-fill, which is fill out a monochrome area. Instead of the recursion and the nearest-Neighbor approach i want the algorithm to be some sort of "turtle" or "mouse" that fills out the image, while leaving a path behind. This path must not contain diagonal movements. The result should be similar to a perfect Snake Game, where the entire square is filled (the snake represents the path in this case). It can cross its own path but that amount should be kept to a minimum and it should only occur in special cases (e.g: when the "mouse" enters a passage of width = 1px, where it would fill that passage out and turn around).The amount of changes in direction it takes should also be kept at a minimum.

P.S: not that this will be applied on an image, not a graph

Comment: This is similar to the [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), which is a difficult problem to solve.

Comment: @user3386109 Just clarify, it is a solvable problem, and many have done it. The problem is that there exists no fast algorithm to solve it.

Comment: What have you done so far. Unlike that [floodfill post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59240491/floodfill-algorithm-leaving-out-the-edge/) I don't see any effort on your part?

Answer (score 0):

I would model this as a graph problem where you are trying to visit all the nodes in the graph. Each pixel is a node and an edge exists between nodes that are directly next to each other.

I believe that creating an algorithm in which is a variation of a breadth first search on a graph modeled like this would achieve the result you were looking for. Ensuring that you do not visit nodes twice.

You would need to delve deeper into the implementation of the breadth first search in order to make sure it prefers a 'straight' path. Possibly when writing the breadth first search logic, create an  `is_straight()` which checks the next node to see if it's straight or not, and prefer the straight node and only pick a non straight node when `is_straight()` returns false on all the child nodes.

Comment: thanks, but im rather new to programming. How do i do this? i can only find stuff on maze solving using this.

Comment: I don't think the straight path is sufficient. (you could cut a legit area in two which will force you to cross an already visited cell). I would bet following the contour, until the center is reached. This avoid btw any need for a stack (in bfs)

Comment: yeah i guess following the contour is the easiest to implement. Are you sure that, by checking if all surrounding pixels are either already visited or out of Bounds, it always implies that we already visited all other pixels? lets say we enter a 3px passage, the pixels to the left and right will be visited leaving the pixel in the middle.  Later on we enter this passage and we end up stuck, which means we cant get out :/

Comment: while your counter example is correct you should focus on coming up to a solution, show implementation, and ask for the remaining problems you can't solve. @man420